# Hive Query to derive the formula for similar column value with in a table

Tags: hive

Column a,b,c,d are available columns in a table.

I need to build a query where to derive "cont_rate" column, for every similar intent_derived_name per date, I need to have the formula `(1- (total_intent_count where intent_derived_name='derived_intent'/total_intenet_count where intent_derived_name='basic_intent')` and wherever per date for basic_intent keep it as '0'

[image]

```
select
    rq_dt,intent_name,
    total_intent_count,Intent_derived_name,
    (1-(case when Intent_derived_name='derived_intent' then total_intent_count end/case when Intent_derived_name='basic_intent' then total_intent_count end )) as cont_rate
from a 
order by rq_dt desc;
```

Kindly help me in building this hql query since i am new to it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)